# AWS Autoscaling Group : Monitoring changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ec2, monitoring, autoscaling

I found a notification mail from AWS that my autoscaling group's desired capacity has been changed from 2 to 1.

Is there any way to find out who made this change? Do I need to check any log or do I need to use any other AWS service to find this sort of information?

Part of the message is below:

```
Description: Terminating EC2 instance: i-xxxxxxxx
Cause: At 2021-02-01T03:08:59Z a user request update of AutoScalingGroup constraints to min: 1, max: 2, desired: 1 changing the desired capacity from 2 to 1.  At 2021-02-01T03:09:01Z an instance was taken out of service in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, shrinking the capacity from 2 to 1.  At 2021-02-01T03:09:01Z instance i-xxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could inspect [CloudTrail Event History](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events.html) for any API events related to autoscaling in the time frame of the incident.

Specifically you could look for [SetDesiredCapacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_SetDesiredCapacity.html) API action.